# Blocking google adsense code in theme: Why isn't this working?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've added this to the header.php in WordPress...

```
<?php // Block Google Adsense on these post ID's?>
    <?php Global $ad_flg; $ad_flg=1; ?>
    <?php $adsense_blck_post = array(7130, 7151); ?> 
    <?php if (in_array($post->ID,$adsense_blck_post,true)) $ad_flg=0; ?>
<?php // STOP Blocking Google Adsense on these post ID's?>
```

Then, to block individual ad spots, I've implemented this code around the ad code.

```
global $ad_flag;
if($ad_flag!=0) {
   echo td_global_blocks::get_instance('td_block_ad_box')->render(array('spot_id' => 'post_style_12'));
```

}

However, when I add it in this example, it's not working. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
        //add the top ad
    global $ad_flag; if (td_util::is_ad_spot_enabled('content_top') and is_single() and $ad_flag!=0) {
        $content = td_global_blocks::get_instance('td_block_ad_box')->render(array('spot_id' => 'content_top')) . $content;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please edit the title to something a bit more appealing

Comment: @AndrewL ... Like?

Answer (score 0):

You're setting a variable called `$ad_flg` and checking one called `$adsense_flag`.  Try using the same name in both places.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that. However, even after adjusting the variable to `$ad_flag`  it's still not working. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, just saw your response.  Glad you got it sorted.  Feel free to upvote and/or accept (hit the check mark) my answer if it helped